# Change other fields value during validation with Formalchemy?

Tags: python, validation, formalchemy

Writing custom [validators](http://docs.formalchemy.org/formalchemy/validators.html) for Formalchemy is simple. During the validation of SOMEFIELD I can access another fields value using `field.parent.SOMEOTHERFIELD.value`.

Is it possible to change SOMEOTHERFIELD's value during the validation of SOMEFIELD? Or should I separate changing related field values from the validation process altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gawel's answer was a step but did not solve my problem (see comment under his answer). I changed the value of  `field.parent.model.SOMEOTHERFIELD` but the change was not committed to the db with `session.commit()`.

After trying out many things I found out that you must use `fieldset.sync()` **before** `field.parent.model.SOMEOTHERFIELD = value`. Only then the change is committed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use field.parent.model.SOMEOTHERFIELD = value

Comment: This changes the value of field.parent.model.SOMEOTHERFIELD but the change is not committed to the db if I do `session.commit()`... How do I commit the change to the DB?